# 'break' not properly in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Want To Make A Calculator Which Is Return Me a Correct Answer. But When I Write Some Specified Numbers. If The User Calculate Those Numbers They Will Have The Wrong Answer Which Is I Set. And My Programme Works But My Programme Gives Me 2 Numbers 1 Is The My Number And The 2nd Is The Correct Answer. I Want Just The Number Which I Set. I Tried This With Break But Break Is Not Working. Python Is Giving Me A Error :
'break' not properly in loop pylint(not-in-loop)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z78G.png
My Code Is:

````
inp=input("Your First Number :    ")
inp1=input("The Symbol You Want To Add :    ")
inp2=input("Your Second Number :    ")
if inp=="45" and inp1=="*" and inp2=="3":
    print("555")
if inp=="56" and inp1=="+" and inp2=="9":
    print("77")
if inp=="56" and inp1=="/" and inp2=="6":
    print("4")
elif inp1=="+":
    print(int(inp)+int(inp2))
    break
elif inp1=="*":
    print(int(inp)*int(inp2))
    break
elif inp1=="-":
    print(int(inp)-int(inp2))
    break
elif inp1=="/":
    print(int(inp)/int(inp2))
    break```
````

Comment: just change  the second and third if statement to elif and remove the breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `break` is used to terminate a loop and it has no effect in a conditional statement.

Also if you want only one conditional statement to satisfy, change every statement to elif except the first one.

```
inp=input("Your First Number :    ")
inp1=input("The Symbol You Want To Add :    ")
inp2=input("Your Second Number :    ")
if inp=="45" and inp1=="*" and inp2=="3":
    print("555")
elif inp=="56" and inp1=="+" and inp2=="9":
    print("77")
elif inp=="56" and inp1=="/" and inp2=="6":
    print("4")
elif inp1=="+":
    print(int(inp)+int(inp2))
elif inp1=="*":
    print(int(inp)*int(inp2))
elif inp1=="-":
    print(int(inp)-int(inp2))
elif inp1=="/":
    print(int(inp)/int(inp2))
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Works Successfully

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're allowed to use `break` statement with if-else statements

`break` is only used in loops. Remove all the break statements and the code will work just fine. Also, one if statement and the rest as elif will do the job better.

```
inp=input("Your First Number :    ")
inp1=input("The Symbol You Want To Add :    ")
inp2=input("Your Second Number :    ")
if inp=="45" and inp1=="*" and inp2=="3":
    print("555")
elif inp=="56" and inp1=="+" and inp2=="9":
    print("77")
elif inp=="56" and inp1=="/" and inp2=="6":
    print("4")
elif inp1=="+":
    print(int(inp)+int(inp2))
elif inp1=="*":
    print(int(inp)*int(inp2))
elif inp1=="-":
    print(int(inp)-int(inp2))
elif inp1=="/":
    print(int(inp)/int(inp2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no loops to `break`, you need to remove your breaks, so your code will look like this:

```py
inp=input("Your First Number :    ")
inp1=input("The Symbol You Want To Add :    ")
inp2=input("Your Second Number :    ")
if inp=="45" and inp1=="*" and inp2=="3":
    print("555")
if inp=="56" and inp1=="+" and inp2=="9":
    print("77")
if inp=="56" and inp1=="/" and inp2=="6":
    print("4")
elif inp1=="+":
    print(int(inp)+int(inp2))
elif inp1=="*":
    print(int(inp)*int(inp2))
elif inp1=="-":
    print(int(inp)-int(inp2))
elif inp1=="/":
    print(int(inp)/int(inp2))
```

But if you are developing a simple calculator there are a lot of other and pythonic ways to write them. If you are interested I can help you.

Btw, the first 3 `if` statements are not really necessary. You can remove them and change the first `elif` to a `if`.